# How to launch multiple instances of the same image in QEMU?

Tags: linux, cluster-computing, qemu

I am launching a guest with:

```
qemu-system-x86-64 \
    -nographic \
    -machine virt \
    -smp 2 \
    -m 4G \
    -bios images/fw_jump.elf \
    -kernel images/Image \
    -append "root=/dev/vda2 ro" \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -drive file=Fedora-38-sda.qcow2,format=qcow2,id=hd0 \
    -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::10000-:22 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=e0 -netdev tap,id=e0 \
    -virtfs local,path=mount/development-toolchain-native,mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0 \
    -virtfs local,path=mount/development-2023-07-13-1400,mount_tag=host1,security_model=passthrough,id=host1
```

I would like to launch simultaneously  more instances like that in order to create a cluster. What should I duplicate in order to have the virtual machines running independently?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  or https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an independent disk for each virtual machine. The easiest solution is to create a new qcow2 image for each vm that uses the original disk as the backing store:

```
for node in {1..10}; do
  drive=node${node}.qcow2
  qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b Fedora-38-sda.qcow2 $drive 10G
  qemu-system-x86-64 \
      -nographic \
      -machine virt \
      -smp 2 \
      -m 4G \
      -bios images/fw_jump.elf \
      -kernel images/Image \
      -append "root=/dev/vda2 ro" \
      -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd0 -drive file=$drive,format=qcow2,id=hd0 \
      -netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::10000-:22 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0 \
      -device virtio-net-device,netdev=e0 -netdev tap,id=e0 \
      -virtfs local,path=mount/development-toolchain-native,mount_tag=host0,security_model=passthrough,id=host0 \
      -virtfs local,path=mount/development-2023-07-13-1400,mount_tag=host1,security_model=passthrough,id=host1
done
```

---

I can't exactly reproduce the command you're running (you haven't provided all the necessary files, and my qemu doesn't have `virt` machine type), but I'm using the following script successfully:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASEIMAGE=Fedora-Cloud-Base-39-1.5.x86_64.qcow2

if ! tmux has-session -t machines; then
  tmux new-session -d -s machines
fi

for node in 1 2 3 4; do
  name=node${node}
  drive="${name}.qcow2}"
  qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b "$BASEIMAGE" "$drive" 10G
  tmux new-window -n "$name" -t machines \
  qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -machine pc \
    -cpu 'Broadwell-v4' \
    -nographic \
    -smp 2 \
    -m 2G \
    -drive file=$drive,format=qcow2,id=virtio-disk0,if=virtio
done
```

This results in four running Fedora 38 virtual machines.

Note that I'm using `tmux` to wrap the qemu execution, since otherwise you would get garbage as multiple nodes output to the same terminal at once.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. When launching only one node I get this:

 [    1.643475] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(254,2) ]---

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how I'm running this succesfully.

Comment: It is weird because the error came from "10G" in qemu-img create. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to use tmux as you stated but I'm getting this error: error connecting to /tmp/tmux-0/default (No such file or directory) Any idea?

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing the exact commands you're running (and the comments on this answer aren't really the right place to diagnose that). If you use the second script for this answer, as written, does it work correctly? It might be worth opening a new question on [unix.se] about using tmux.

Comment: I'm using your script but with my QEMU image. Nevertheless, it works. I cannot access the tmux though.